How to make a POST request using react-hook-from and zod in nextjs 14.2
I am a beginner. I am trying to make a post request to the express server. I am using typeScript and Shadcn/ui form with zod validation. I have to make a POST request like this JSON object below. I am getting the location dynamically from the server. How do I send the request ?
{
  "description": "New Activity",
  "price": 50,
  "durationInMinutes": 120,
  "placeId":1,
  "locationId":1,
  "status": "available"
} 

This is my code of the form to make POST request but this is not working. The validation following
export const createActivityValidation = z.object({
  description: z
    .string({
      required_error: "Description required",
      invalid_type_error: "Description must be characters",
    })
    .min(1, "Description Needs More than 1 character"),
  durationInMinutes: z.number(),
  price: z.number(),
  status: z
    .string({
      required_error: "Status required",
      invalid_type_error: "Description must be characters",
    })
    .min(1, "Status is required"),
  location: z.string({
    required_error: "Place required",
    invalid_type_error: "Please select the place",
  }),
});

Every time I submit the form zod validation throws error as Expected number but got string whereas I have the validation as number.

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState<Location[]>([]);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof createActivityValidation>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(createActivityValidation),
  });

  const onSubmit = async (value: z.infer<typeof createActivityValidation>) => {
    console.log("value", value);
    try {
      setLoading(true);

      const activityConfig = {
        description: value.description,
        durationInMinutes: value.durationInMinutes,
        price: value.price,
        status: value.status,
        location: value.location,
      };

      const activityCreation = await fetcher.post(
        "activities/activities",
        activityConfig,
      );
      toast.success("Activity Created Successfully!");
      console.log(activityCreation.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      toast.error("Failed to create new Activity", {
        description: "Something went wrong Please try later",
      });
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
        <Form {...form}>
          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-2">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="description"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Description</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Activity Description"
                      {...field}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="durationInMinutes"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Duration</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      type="number"
                      placeholder="Duration of activities in minutes"
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        const value = Number(e.target.value);
                        field.onChange(value);
                      }}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="price"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Price</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      type="number"
                      placeholder="Price"
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        const value = Number(e.target.value);
                        field.onChange(value);
                      }}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="status"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Status</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="available or unavailabe"
                      {...field}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="status"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Status</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <LocationSelector
                      value={field.value}
                      onChange={field.onChange}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
             <Button
                variant="outline"
                size="sm"
                type="submit"
                className="bg-primary text-secondary rounded-full gap-2"
                disabled={loading}
              >
                {loading ? (
                  <span className="flex">
                    <CircleDashed size={20} className=" mr-1 animate-spin" />
                    Loading
                  </span>
                ) : (
                  <span className="flex">
                    <PlusIcon size={20} />
                    Create
                  </span>
                )}
          </Button>
  );
}



That's a lot of code. Please try making a Minimal, Reproducible Example

The issue here is that even if you set type="number" on the input field for duration and price, in the form when submitting the data that is being received is string.
You can get through in two ways.

Use z.number.or(z.string()) instead of z.number() and manually typecasting inside of onSubmit as
data.price = Number(data.price)

Use the controller from react-hook-form to typecast the input string to number on every onChange event.


import { useForm, Controller, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";


const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<SchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  });





<Controller
              control={control}
              name="price"
              render={({
                field: { value, onChange },
              }) => (
                <input
                  value={value}
                  placeholder="Enter price"
                  type="number"
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(Number(e.target.value))}
                />
              )}
            />



